# how do i insert php variable in html mail file

Tags: php, html, email

i have a php file to generate otp and sending   html mail to user but i am unable to insert php variable it beacuse i am getting html mail content from other file please help me to do it

i want to insert below variable in html
$otpemail
$name

here is my php code

```
  if (isset($_POST['resend'])) {
    $uid = $_SESSION['usr_id'];
    $otpemail=mt_rand(100000,999999);
    $subject = "Email verification";
    $email_from= "Go Alert <verification@goalert.in>";
    $email_reply = "feedback@goalert.in";
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n". 'Reply-To: '.$email_reply."\r\n" .'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $user =$db->getemail($uid);
    if($user != NULL){
        $email = $user['email'];
        $name = $user['name'];
        $status = "Not Verified";
        $messageemail = file_get_contents('email.html');
        $user=$db->resendemailotp($uid,$name,$email,$otpemail,$status);
        @mail($email, $subject, $messageemail, $headers);
        $errormsg1 = "Email Sent Please Check Spam if not recived";

    }else {
          $errormsg1 = "Error in Sending Email";
    }
}
```

my html mail file codes are

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="en" style="background: #f0f0f0; min-height: 100%;" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <meta content="width=device-width" name="viewport" />
 </head>
 <body style="box-sizing: border-box; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; min-width: 100%; padding: 0; text-align: left; width: 100% !important;">
  <table class="body" style="background: #f0f0f0; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; height: 100%; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
   <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
    <td align="center" class="center" style="border-collapse: collapse !important; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; hyphens: auto; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; word-wrap: break-word;" valign="top">
     <center data-parsed="" style="min-width: 580px; width: 100%;">
      <table class="container text-center" style="background: #fefefe; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: 580px;">
       <tbody>
        <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
         <td style="border-collapse: collapse !important; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; hyphens: auto; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; word-wrap: break-word;">
          <!-- This container adds the gap at the top of the email -->
          <table class="row grey" style="background: #f0f0f0; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; display: table; padding: 0; position: relative; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
           <tbody>
            <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
             <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first last" style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 16px; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 16px; text-align: left; width: 564px;">
              <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
               <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                <th style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left;"> &#xA0; </th>
                <th class="expander" style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; padding: 0 !important; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0;">
                </th>
               </tr>
              </table>
             </th>
            </tr>
           </tbody>
          </table>
         </td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      <table class="container text-center" style="background: #fefefe; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: 580px;">
       <tbody>
        <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
         <td style="border-collapse: collapse !important; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; hyphens: auto; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; word-wrap: break-word;">
          <!-- Main email content -->
          <table class="row" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; display: table; padding: 0; position: relative; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
           <tbody>
            <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
             <!-- Logo -->
             <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first last" style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 16px; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 16px; text-align: left; width: 564px;">
              <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
               <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                <th style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left;">
                 <center data-parsed="" style="min-width: 532px; width: 100%;"><a align="center" class="text-center" href="http://www.goalert.in" style="color: #f7931d; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; text-decoration: none;"> <img alt="Logo Image" class="swu-logo" src="https://www.goalert.in/test/assets/images/logo.png" style="border: none; clear: both; display: block; height: auto; max-width: 100%; outline: none; padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px; text-decoration: none; width: 170px;" /> </a></center>
                </th>
                <th class="expander" style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; padding: 0 !important; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0;">
                </th>
               </tr>
              </table>
             </th>
            </tr>
           </tbody>
          </table>
          <table class="row masthead" style="background: #212121; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; display: table; padding: 0; position: relative; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
           <tbody>
            <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
             <!-- Masthead -->
             <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first last" style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 16px; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 16px; text-align: left; width: 564px;">
              <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
               <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                <th style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left;">
                 <h1 class="text-center" style="color: #f7931d; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 34px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 35px 0px 15px 0px; text-align: center; word-wrap: normal;">Download our Application</h1>
                 <center data-parsed="" style="min-width: 532px; width: 100%;"><a align="center" class="text-center" href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.com.goalert" style="color: #f7931d; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; text-decoration: none;"> <img align="center" alt="Masthead Image" class="text-center" src="https://www.goalert.in/test/assets/images/play.png" style="border: none; clear: both; display: block; float: none; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 100%; outline: none; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; width: auto;" valign="bottom" /> </a></center>
                </th>
                <th class="expander" style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; padding: 0 !important; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0;">
                </th>
               </tr>
              </table>
             </th>
            </tr>
           </tbody>
          </table>
          <table class="row" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; display: table; padding: 0; position: relative; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
           <tbody>
            <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
             <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first last" style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 16px; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 16px; text-align: left; width: 564px;">
              <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
               <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                <th style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left;"> &#xA0; <!--This container adds the gap between masthead and digest content -->
                </th>
                <th class="expander" style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; padding: 0 !important; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0;">
                </th>
               </tr>
              </table>
             </th>
            </tr>
           </tbody>
          </table>
          <table class="row" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; display: table; padding: 0; position: relative; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
           <tbody>
            <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
             <!-- Email copy -->
             <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first last" style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 16px; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 16px; text-align: left; width: 564px;">
              <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
               <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                <th style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left;">
                 <h5 style="color: inherit; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0; text-align: left; word-wrap: normal;">Hi, {{name}}</h5>
                 <p style="color: #777777 !important; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0; text-align: left;">Thankyou for suscribing with Go Alert.Now receive all application notifiaction into your mailbox.For faster information download our official mobile application from <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.com.goalert" style="color: #f7931d; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; text-decoration: none;"> here</a></p>
                 <br />
                 <hr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #cacaca; border-left: 0; border-right: 0; border-top: 0; clear: both; height: 0; margin: 20px auto; max-width: 580px;" />
                </th>
                <th class="expander" style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; padding: 0 !important; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0;">
                </th>
               </tr>
              </table>
             </th>
            </tr>
           </tbody>
          </table>
          <table class="row" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; display: table; padding: 0; position: relative; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
           <tbody>
            <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
             <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first last" style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 16px; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 16px; text-align: left; width: 564px;">
              <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
               <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                <th style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left;">
                 <h5 class="text-center" style="color: inherit; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0; text-align: center; word-wrap: normal;">Your OTP is</h5>
                </th>
                <th class="expander" style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; padding: 0 !important; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0;">
                </th>
               </tr>
              </table>
             </th>
            </tr>
           </tbody>
          </table>
          <table class="row" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; display: table; padding: 0; position: relative; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
           <tbody>
            <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
             <!-- Coupon code box -->
             <th class="small-12 large-4 columns first" style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 16px; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 8px; text-align: left; width: 177.33333px;">
              <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
               <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                <th style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left;">
                </th>
               </tr>
              </table>
             </th>
             <th class="grey small-12 large-12 columns" style="background: #f0f0f0; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 16px; padding-left: 8px; padding-right: 8px; text-align: left; width: 564px;">
              <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
               <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                <th style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left;">
                 <br />
                 <h5 class="text-center" style="color: inherit; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0; text-align: center; word-wrap: normal;" valign="middle">2ob3-32cc39-2pe3-291ab</h5>
                </th>
                <th class="expander" style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; padding: 0 !important; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0;">
                </th>
               </tr>
              </table>
             </th>
             <th class="small-12 large-4 columns last" style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 16px; padding-left: 8px; padding-right: 16px; text-align: left; width: 177.33333px;">
              <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
               <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                <th style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left;">
                </th>
               </tr>
              </table>
             </th>
            </tr>
           </tbody>
          </table>
          <table class="row" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; display: table; padding: 0; position: relative; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
           <tbody>
            <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
             <!-- Call to Action -->
             <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first last" style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 16px; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 16px; text-align: left; width: 564px;">
              <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
               <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                <th style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left;">
                 <center data-parsed="" style="min-width: 532px; width: 100%;">
                  <br align="center" class="text-center" />
                  <br align="center" class="text-center" />
                  <table class="button text-center" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin: 0 0 16px 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: auto !important;">
                   <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                    <td style="border-collapse: collapse !important; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; hyphens: auto; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; word-wrap: break-word;">
                     <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                      <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                       <td style="background: #f7931d; border: 2px solid #f7931d; border-collapse: collapse !important; color: #fefefe; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; hyphens: auto; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: auto !important; word-wrap: break-word;"><a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.com.goalert" style="border: 0px solid #f7931d; border-radius: 3px; color: #fefefe; display: inline-block; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 8px 16px 8px 16px; text-align: left; text-decoration: none;">Download Our Application </a></td>
                      </tr>
                     </table>
                    </td>
                   </tr>
                  </table>
                 </center>
                </th>
                <th class="expander" style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; padding: 0 !important; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0;">
                </th>
               </tr>
              </table>
             </th>
            </tr>
           </tbody>
          </table>
          <table class="row" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; display: table; padding: 0; position: relative; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
           <tbody>
            <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
             <!--This row adds the gap between masthead and digest content -->
             <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first last" style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 16px; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 16px; text-align: left; width: 564px;">
              <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
               <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                <th style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left;"> &#xA0; </th>
                <th class="expander" style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; padding: 0 !important; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0;">
                </th>
               </tr>
              </table>
             </th>
            </tr>
           </tbody>
          </table>
         </td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      <!-- / End main email content -->
      <table class="container text-center" style="background: #fefefe; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: 580px;">
       <tbody>
        <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
         <td style="border-collapse: collapse !important; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; hyphens: auto; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; word-wrap: break-word;">
          <table class="row grey" style="background: #f0f0f0; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; display: table; padding: 0; position: relative; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
           <tbody>
            <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
             <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first last" style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 16px; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 16px; text-align: left; width: 564px;">
              <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
               <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                <th style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left;">
                 <p class="text-center footercopy" style="color: #777777 !important; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 20px 0px; text-align: center;">&#xA9; Copyright 2016 Go Alert. All Rights Reserved.</p>
                </th>
                <th class="expander" style="color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; margin: 0; padding: 0 !important; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0;">
                </th>
               </tr>
              </table>
             </th>
            </tr>
           </tbody>
          </table>
         </td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
     </center>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick/dirty, use the output buffering system:

foo.html

```
<div><?php echo $var ?></div>
```

main script:

```
ob_start();
$var = 'hi mom!';
include('foo.html'); // executes any php code in the file
$html = ob_end_clean();
```

Alternatively, you could use a simple templating system:

foo.html:

```
<div>%VAR%</div>
```

main script:

```
$raw_html = file_get_contents('foo.html');
$var = 'hi mom!';
$complete_html = str_replace('%VAR%', $var, $raw_html);
```

Comment: if($user != NULL){
     $email = $user['email'];
     $name = $user['name'];
     include('email.html');
     ob_end_clean();
     $messageemail= file_get_contents('email.html');

     $status = "Not Verified";